# Simple example of linear approximation with multivariable calc - is this right?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

I'm still trying to grasp fully the concept of directional derivatives and how they can be used to approximate functions, and so I have an example of a problem I made up that I tried to evaluate. Let's say I have the function,

$$f(x,y) = x^2+y^2$$

I want to evaluate the directional derivative at the point P = $(2,2,8)$ with the vector $\vec{v} = (1,2)$.

So I first found the gradient $\nabla f = (2x,2y)$, and plugging in the original points I got the gradient at point P to be $(4,4)$. I then found $\nabla f \cdot P$ and got $4 * 1 + 4 * 2 = 12$. So the directional derivative would be $12$. My understanding is that this is the best approximation around the point, and says that moving by $h*\vec{v}$ will cause a change of $12 * h$. So when $h=1$, you would be moving to the point (2,3) and the approximation would be $f \approx 8 + 12 = 20$, but the actual value of the function is $f = 25$.  That's a very large error, but when $h$ gets smaller and smaller, this error will decrease monotonically.

I want to clarify if my logic, calculation, and reasoning is correct before I move on from this topic. I'd be worried if I went into the next topic with a fundamental misunderstanding.

Comment: You are missing that the direction has to be a unit vector.

Comment: @Kaynex from my question here, it seems that you do not actually need to scale down to a unit vector: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2291302/why-isnt-the-directional-derivative-generally-scaled-down-to-the-unit-vector

Comment: I'm not sure what's going on in your question, but it's clear here that changing the length of your direction should not matter, yet if you multiply your direction vector by $2$, you're going to double your result.

Comment: That's true, except the directional derivative supposedly does indeed have that property, in most cases. Take a look at the section "finding slope" from [Khan Academy](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/multivariable-calculus/multivariable-derivatives/partial-derivative-and-gradient-articles/a/directional-derivative-introduction) - this is where I'm learning it from, and I hear that definitions do differ. But regardless of the approach, shouldn't the linearization yield the same result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, as someone said in the comments, the formula $\nabla f \cdot \vec{v}$ for directional derivative only holds when $\vec{v}$ is a unit vector.  What you are doing is almost correct, and it is similar in flavor to the directional derivative, but you are *not* computing the directional derivative.  Careful with the terminology here.

You can use your approach to estimate the value of $f$ at some point 'near' $P = (2, 2)$.  You are using a vector $\vec{v} = (1, 2)$ and taking $h=1$.  That means you are trying to approximate $f$ at the point $P + \vec{v} = (3, 4)$.  Using the directional derivative method, you estimated $f(3, 4) \approx 20$, but we calculate $f(3, 4) = 25$.  Frankly, this isn't too bad of an approximation. Note that the point $(3, 4)$ is $\sqrt{5} \approx 2.2$ units aways from the original point $(2,2)$.  This is kind of far to be expecting super close approximations.  So being off by $5$ isn't so bad.  If you try the same thing but take $h = 0.1$ or even $h = 0.001$, you will see that the error shrinks dramatically.

Comment: Thank you! You thoroughly answered my question - but with the directional derivative, I'm confused because it seems like most commonly it isn't scaled down to a unit vector, or at least it's a matter of style. What are your thoughts? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directional_derivative#Definition

Comment: @rb612 There is a difference between the *definition* of the directional derivative (like the wikipedia definitions you linked) and a convenient method for computing it.  You don't need $\vec{v}$ to be a unit vector if you use the limit definition of directional derivative.  You do however need to take $\vec{v}$ to be a unit vector to use the convenient $\nabla f\cdot \vec{v}$ method of computing the directional derivative.

Comment: What you're saying makes a lot of sense - I'm just wondering why (and I'm going purely off of what I've learned from Grant on [KhanAcademy](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/multivariable-calculus/multivariable-derivatives/partial-derivative-and-gradient-articles/a/directional-derivative-introduction) that he says you only need to scale down to a unit vector if you're using it to compute slope. He doesn't scale it down for any other circumstance. Could you please help me understand? Thank you!

Comment: @rb612 The directional derivative *is* the 'slope' of the tangent plane in the direction of $\vec{v}$.  They are the same thing.  Most people avoid the term 'slope' in this context because talking about the 'slope' of a plane doesn't always make sense.

Comment: ah thank you! But do the calculations work out the same? Like if I scaled it down to a unit vector and then did the magnitude times the directional derivative, I would get the same result always as if I were just taking the dot product with the original vector, right? In other words, scaling doesn't change the computation, merely the terminology used?

Comment: @rb612 That is correct